# SVG text - one text left align and other text in same line has to be right align

Tags: svg

I have the following items list and its prices to be displayed in SVG format.

Bottles ...........$5.00
Description of the bottles

Desktop accessories...........$25.00
Description of the Desktop accessories

Can anyone help me to layout the price at the right hand side of svgList as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WRKB.jpg) also shown below.

Bottles ................................. $5.00
Description of the bottles

Desktop accessories...........   $25.00
Description of the Desktop accessories

The SVG code is as follows :

```
<svg id=“svgList” width="816" height="400" class="myBGImage">
        <g id="main">

            <g id="subGroup01" class="group" transform="translate(20,100)" style="cursor: move; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <text alignment-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="start" data-type="itemtitle" id="itemtitle_h0f0" class="roboto_global fontSize_20g" stroke-width="2" color="#000000">
                <tspan class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Bottles</tspan>
                <tspan class="dots" text-anchor="start">...............</tspan>
                <tspan class="price" text-anchor="start">$5.00</tspan>
                <tspan class="item-desc" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20">Description </tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="subGroup02" class="group" transform="translate(20,150)" style="cursor: move; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <text alignment-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="start" data-type="itemtitle" id="itemtitle_h0f1" class="roboto_global fontSize_20g" stroke-width="2" color="#000000">
                <tspan class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Desktop accessories</tspan>
                <tspan class="dots" text-anchor="start">...............</tspan>
                <tspan class="price" text-anchor="start">$25.00</tspan>
                <tspan class="item-desc" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20">Description </tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anujas/yrk5nsr6/2/)

Comment: Why do you use SVG? Text layout is really something HTML is much more fitting for.

Comment: I require this as this list has to be printed. And SVG gives good resolution

Comment: both of those requirements can be met by html too.

Comment: hmm i know that HTML is the best for the text layout, but by any chance is there any way out using SVG in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `text-anchor="start"`, did you try `text-anchor="end"`?

That deals with the alignment issue. The only slightly tricky bit is how to do the variable width dots, without having to have to work out exactly how many dots you need to use in each case.

The approach I've used in my solution (see bottom example) is to use a dotted line.

```html
<svg id="svgList" width="816" height="400" class="myBGImage">
  <g transform="translate(20,100)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="250" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke="1" stroke-dasharray="2 2"/>
    <text class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Bottles</text>
    <text class="price" text-anchor="end" x="250">$5.00</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then to hide the dots behind the text, we add an extra copy of the text behind the original text. Then we give that extra copy of the text a thick white stroke to hide the relevant section of the dotted line.  It has the effect of a white "halo" around the text to obliterate the part of the dotted line behind our text.

In this little snippet, I've made the stroke/halo blue to show what's happening.

```html
<svg id="svgList" width="816" height="400" class="myBGImage">
  <g transform="translate(20,100)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="250" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke="1" stroke-dasharray="2 2"/>
    <use xlink:href="#row1" stroke="blue" stroke-width="6"/>
    <g id="row1" fill="white">
      <text class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Bottles</text>
      <text class="price" text-anchor="end" x="250">$5.00</text>
    </g>
    <text class="item-desc" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20">Description </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The final result:

```html
<svg id="svgList" width="816" height="400" class="myBGImage">
  <g id="main">

    <g id="subGroup01" class="group" transform="translate(20,100)" style="cursor: move; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="250" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke="1" stroke-dasharray="2 2"/>
      <use xlink:href="#row1" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"/>
      <g id="row1">
        <text class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Bottles</text>
        <text class="price" text-anchor="end" x="250">$5.00</text>
      </g>
      <text class="item-desc" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20">Description </text>
    </g>

    <g id="subGroup02" class="group" transform="translate(20,150)" style="cursor: move; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="250" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke="1" stroke-dasharray="2 2"/>
      <use xlink:href="#row2" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"/>
      <g id="row2">
        <text class="item" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Desktop accessories</text>
        <text class="price" text-anchor="end" x="250">$25.00</text>
      </g>
      <text class="item-desc" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20">Description </text>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: hey @Paul LeBeau, thanks the code was very helpful, on the dotted line, for me the challenge is I am having a background image attached to the svgList. If it was just background color than it is possible to handle by giving the stroke the same color as that of background. Any tweak you could suggest while working with the background image? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anujas/yrk5nsr6/2/)

Comment: Yes. Instead of painting white (as above) to hide the dots, use that extra text element(s) to make a `<mask>` instead.

Comment: will that mask blend with the background image given to the svglist? if yes then I should be trying this.

Comment: Yes. You are only masking out parts of the dotted line. It will not affect any background.